# Cannot pass struct parameters via $.ajax to a controller using ASP.NET (with MVC2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, struct

I have a model class like this:

```
namespace Models
{
   public struct Localization
   {
      public int Id;
      public string LanguageName;
      public string LanguageCode;
      public DateTime LastUpdate;
   }

   public class LocalizationModel
   {
      private List<Localization> _localization;

      public LocalizationModel() {
         Browse();
      }

        //create simple list
      public void Browse() {
         Localization lang = new Localization();
         _localization = new List<Localization>();

         for ( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
            lang.Id = i;
            lang.LanguageName = "Language name " + i;
            lang.LanguageCode = "Language code " + i;
            lang.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

            _localization.Add( lang );
         }
      }

      public bool AddNewLanguage( Localization item ) {
         if ( ( item as object ) == null ) {
            throw new ArgumentException( "The localization cannot be empty" );
         }

         _localization.Add( item );

         return true;
      }

      public List<Localization> LocalizationList {
         get {
            return _localization;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the **Add** method defined in Home Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add( Localization sendInfo ) {
           bool success = _localization.AddNewLanguage( sendInfo );

           return this.Json( new {
              msg = success
           } );
        }
```

I called that method from jquery ajax function like this:

```
function sendDataForAdd() {
   var sendInfo = { Id: 0,
      LanguageName: $("#lang-name").val(),
      LanguageCode: $("#lang-code").val(),
      LastUpdate: $("#lang-update").val()
   };

   $.post('/Home/Add', sendInfo, doneLanguageAdded, 'json');

   function doneLanguageAdded(msg) {
      if (msg) {
         alert("The language was added successfully !");
         window.location.refresh(true);
      }
      else {
         alert("The language was not added in list !");
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that the `Add` function parameter -> `sendInfo` from controller becomes null. 
The javascript variables take correctly the input values.
The problem is the `struct` from Model or what ?

I tried other scenario. I defined a class with all properties and use it in `LocalizationModel` class. It works perfectly with jquery ajax and pass correct parameter to controller function.

Why if I use `struct`, the controller parameter is null ? There are a trick ?

I put a breakpoint to controller function (using Visual Studio) and I checked the parameter.

Id and other variables are null. I attached a picture:
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct needs to have getters and setters.

```
public struct Localization
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string {get; set;}
  public string {get; set;}
  public DateTime {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Travis, that's why my script not working... Thank you :) God bless you :D